Transform repeatable subelements to columns
First of all I'm very new to power query ... I have similar xml as bellow:
<root>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <otherData>
        <id>1</id>
      </otherData>
      <images>
        <image>
          <url>http://example.com/1.img</url>
        </image>
        <image>
          <url>http://example.com/1.img</url>
        </image>
        <image>
          <url>http://example.com/1.img</url>
        </image>
      </images>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <otherData>
        <id>2</id>
      </otherData>
      <images>
        <image>
          <url>http://example.com/4.img</url>
        </image>
        <image>
          <url>http://example.com/5.img</url>
        </image>
      </images>
    </entry>
  </entries>
<root>

what I want is to have a table which consists of id and then dynamic number of columns based on /images/image/url. I don't know if it's possible to add columns dynamically and name them somehow (with number suffix img1 ... imgN)



id
img1
img2
img3




1
http://example.com/1.img
http://example.com/2.img
http://example.com/3.img|


2
http://example.com/4.img
http://example.com/5.img





I think you can first load XML into powerquery, and then keep clicking the "Expand Column" icon:

Until your table looks like below:

Then you will need to open the advance editor and write your own M code to transform the table into your desired format.
The code I use is this:
let
  Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents("/Users/userName/Documents/test.xml")),
  // below code are generated by clicking "expand column" icon
  #"Expanded Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table", {"Name", "Table"}, {"Name.1", "Table.1"}),
  #"Expanded Table.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Table", "Table.1", {"otherData", "images"}, {"otherData", "images"}),
  #"Expanded otherData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Table.1", "otherData", {"id"}, {"id"}),
  #"Expanded images" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded otherData", "images", {"image"}, {"image"}),

  
  // below codes are written by hand
  GetUrls = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded images", "urls", (row)=> row[image][url]),
  GetHeaders = Table.AddColumn(GetUrls, "headers", (row)=>List.Transform({1..List.Count(row[urls])}, (x)=> "Image" & Number.ToText(x))),
  AllHeaders = List.Distinct(List.Combine(GetHeaders[headers])),
  CreateUrlsByHeader = Table.AddColumn(GetHeaders, "urlsByHeader", (row)=> Record.FromList(row[urls], row[headers])),
  SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(CreateUrlsByHeader, {"id", "urlsByHeader"}),
  #"Expanded urlsByHeader" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(SelectColumns, "urlsByHeader", AllHeaders, AllHeaders)
in
  #"Expanded urlsByHeader"

Results:


thanks for answer...is there any chance to have some nullcheck when there is no row[image][url] - sometimes those images are not present.

seems like this works, don't know if that's the correct behaviour (row)=> if row[image] <> null &&  row[image][url] <> null then  row[image][url] else {}

You may want to look at Solved: Re: URL validation - Microsoft Fabric Community

@bilak, yes, using an empty list when row[image][url] is null is exactly what I would do. and I check, when urls is an empty list, {1..List.Count(row[urls]} will also evaluate to an empty list without exception.

Very nice @rachel - learning more PQ from you!
